# Where to find the attribute mentioned in xsl: value of tag

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my first experience with xsl. I have a dropdown where I need to a new value. Till now I have figured out which attribute is used to populate the dropdown, but cannot find where the attribute is defined. Below is the section for dropdown.

```
<select id="idProgram" name="recog_cd" size="1">
   <!-- force default program to be listed first -->
   <xsl:for-each select="program">
      <xsl:if test="@recog_cd = $default_program_sel">
         <option value="{@recog_cd}">
            <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="@recog_cd = $sel_recog_cd">
                  <xsl:attribute name="selected">yes</xsl:attribute>
               </xsl:when>
               <xsl:when test="@recog_cd = $input[@name='recog_cd']">
                  <xsl:attribute name="selected">yes</xsl:attribute>
               </xsl:when>
               <xsl:when test="@recog_cd = $default_program_sel">
                  <xsl:attribute name="selected">yes</xsl:attribute>
               </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
         </option>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
```

What I want to know is where can "@name" be. As i understand, @ Selects attributes(from w3schools.com), but I don't find any attribute "name". So, for ex: default_program_sel above is defined as a variable as below:

```
<xsl:variable name="default_program_sel">
   <xsl:value-of select="../cis_page_header/@default_program_sel"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

I am able to find default_program_sel in a XMLPluginClass.

```
builder.addAttribute("default_program_sel", "CE");
```

I am looking for something similar for @name, but with no luck.
Any help is appreciated.

Extra: If possible can someone let me know how can I print on page the result of sel_recog_cd(basically how to print any expression) ? I did -

```
Some value<xsl:value-of select="@sel_recog_cd" />
```

but only Some value was printed.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid your question is extremely confusing. The likely reason for this is that you haven't mastered the basic concepts and terminology of XSLT well enough to use language that XSLT people will understand. There's too much missing in your code fragment: we don't know what the XML source document looks like, we don't know what's in variables such as $input, and we don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: There are two different @name attributes in your code, one on $input and one on the context item, and it's not clear which you are asking about. Finally, you refer to see_recog_cd both as a variable (with $) and as an attribute (with @).

Comment: Agreed, I am running behind schedule, so I posted the question to check if I can get some guiding inputs.

Comment: Oh dear. Being behind schedule on an assignment where you are new to the relevant technology is bad news. Taking short-cuts by implementing a solution you don't fully understand is a recipe for severe quality problems. It's time to alert your manager to the fact that they either need to change the schedule, or hire a consultant who can do it without the steep learning curve you are facing.

Comment: hmm.. seems the right thing to do. I will look around if I find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the statement

```xml
<xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
```

... the XPath expression `@name` is a "relative" XPath because it doesn't start with a `/` (the root of the document). So it's evaluated relative to a current node (called the "context node" in XPath).

So you will need to look for an XSLT statement which is an ancestor of this `value-of` statement, and which sets the context node. If you walk back up the tree from the `value-of` statement, looking for `xsl:` elements, you'll find a `choose` and an `if` (neither of which affect the context node) and finally a `for-each` (which *does* affect the context node):

```xml
<xsl:for-each select="program">
   ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

This `for-each` element has the effect of repeatedly executing its content nodes, each time with a different context node, drawn from the set of `program` elements. Note that the XPath expression `program` is *also* a relative XPath, but the context node in this case is determined by code which is outside of what you've posted in your question. You will need to walk back up the tree to find it, in the same way as I've explained for `@name`.

Comment: Your solution helped me to get a better understanding of the code, thanks. But, I don't see any ancestor to <xsl:for-each select="program">. It is inside a <select >, which is inside <td>, which as per your comment, doesn't affect the context node. Is there somewhere that I should be looking at?

Comment: That `<xsl:for-each select="program">` must have some other ancestor elements in the XSLT namespace. Probably there'll be an `<xsl:template match="foo">` which will imply that the context element is a `<foo>` element, or there might be some other `<xsl:for-each>` whose `select` attribute will provide the context.

Comment: The only ancestor node to this is - <xsl:template name="foo">.

Comment: For a template that's called by name, the context node will not change. So the context will be whatever the context was when `<xsl:call-template name="foo"/>` was called.